# How to delay a minutely cron for an hour

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-12.04

I have a cron that needs to run every minute until a certain event happens then i need it to stop running until the next hour. I have looked around and all i can seem to find is how to run crons on different intervals not how to disable it until the next hour starts then re-enable it.

Any help or suggestions to a solution would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron runs programs periodically: that's all it does. It doesn't have facilities to do things "optionally". If you want to do something clever you need to handle it on your side. e.g.:

- Write the time into a file when your event occurs and read the file at the start of your "job" to see if the job should run or not.

Comment: Do you know of a way to disable a cron in the cron tab then re-enable it? If not ill just do this all inside my script

Comment: Easiest way is to do it in your script. Anything else is "getting hacky"